Prime check by Digit prefix or postfix
Each Prime can (mostly) be generated by having an existing Prime, then padding it either in front or back by a single digit (and the resulting number will be a Prime as well).
example:
23 is a Prime, Add a 2 in front: 223 is also a Prime
11 is a Prime, Add a 3 in the back: 113 is also a Prime 

Now there are some Primes that this pattern does not exist for. I am trying to see which ones do not fit this category.
So If I start by getting a few Primes, then pad them and see if results are Prime:
Front-padding:
FromDigits@*Flatten@*IntegerDigits /@ 
 Select[Tuples[{Range[9], Prime[Range[10]]}], 
  PrimeQ[FromDigits[
     Join[IntegerDigits[#[[1]]], IntegerDigits[#[[2]]]]]]
   &]

===>
{13, 17, 113, 23, 211, 223, 229, 37, 311, 313, 317, 43, 47, 419, 53, 523, 67, 613, 617, 619, 73, 719, 83, 811, 823, 829, 97, 911, 919, 929}

Back-padding:
FromDigits@*Flatten@*IntegerDigits /@ 
 Select[Tuples[{Prime[Range[10]], Range[10] - 1}], 
  PrimeQ[FromDigits[
     Join[IntegerDigits[#[[1]]], IntegerDigits[#[[2]]]]]]
   &]

===>
{23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 71, 73, 79, 113, 131, 137, 139, 173, 179, 191, 193, 197, 199, 233, 239, 293}

Those are also all Primes - however this is just giving me a list. I need to:
1-Merge them into a single list, ordered.
2-More importantly, see which original primes did not have a resulting Prime. Those need to be identified.  (Ex: 773) - If we expand the original Range of 10

Have you seen Union[] (for merging and sorting lists)?

The primes that do not satisfy the condition appears to be A240843 in OEIS

Select[Prime[Range[1000]], 
 Not[Or @@ 
    PrimeQ[Join[(f |-> FromDigits@Prepend[IntegerDigits[#], f]) /@ 
       Range[9], (f |-> FromDigits@Append[IntegerDigits[#], f]) /@ 
       Range[9]]]] &]


{773, 1103, 1301, 3947, 3989, 4241, 4637, 4931, 5039, 5387, 5417,
6803, 6917, 6971, 7229, 7451, 7703, 7753}


Ha! What a coincidence: We both picked the first 1000 primes for a test. (I guess you did it for the same reason I did: The first 100 didn't contain any primes that failed.)

Write a function to check a prime (assumes p is a prime for efficiency):
goodP[p_] := With[{nextPower = 10^Ceiling@Log10[N@p]},
   AnyTrue[Join[Range[9] nextPower + p, 10*p + {1, 3, 7, 9}], PrimeQ]];

Pick the "bad" primes:
With[{primes = Prime[Range[1000]]}, 
 Pick[primes, goodP /@ primes, False]]
(*
{773, 1103, 1301, 3947, 3989, 4241, 4637, 4931, 5039, 5387, 5417, 
 6803, 6917, 6971, 7229, 7451, 7703, 7753}
*)

The following groups primes by whether the task succeeds:
pdata = With[{primes = Prime[Range[1000]]}, GroupBy[primes, goodP]];

pdata[False]
(*
{773, 1103, 1301, 3947, 3989, 4241, 4637, 4931, 5039, 5387, 5417, 
 6803, 6917, 6971, 7229, 7451, 7703, 7753}
*)

pdata[True] // Short

(*  {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, <<968>>, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919}  *)


Here is a function that returns True if a prime adheres to the pattern and False otherwise:
check[p_] := Module[{d = IntegerDigits[p], r = Range[0, 9]},
  pre = FromDigits /@  (Prepend[d, #] & /@ Rest@r  );
  end = FromDigits /@  (Append[d, #] & /@ r  );
  AnyTrue[Join[pre, end], PrimeQ]
  ]

To get an ordered list of primes that fullfill the pattern:
Select[Table[Prime[i], {i, 2, 100}], check]

{3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, \
71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, \
149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, \
227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, \
307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, \
389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, \
467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541}

And a list of primes that do not:
Select[Table[Prime[i], {i, 2, 1000}], ! check[#] &]

{773, 1103, 1301, 3947, 3989, 4241, 4637, 4931, 5039, 5387, 5417, \
6803, 6917, 6971, 7229, 7451, 7703, 7753}


paddedPrimes[k_Integer /; k > 0] := FromDigits /@ Join[
    Thread@Prepend[IntegerDigits[k], Range[1, 9]]
    , Thread@Append[IntegerDigits[k], Range[1, 9, 2]]
    ] // Select[PrimeQ]

Usage
Prime[Range[1, PrimePi[10000]]] // 
 Select[EqualTo[0]@*Length@*paddedPrimes]



{773, 1103, 1301, 3947, 3989, 4241, 4637, 4931, 5039, 5387, 5417, 
6803, 6917, 6971, 7229, 7451, 7703, 7753}

